# "That position is not loaded" error when trying to fill

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to fill a space (basically trying to fill a hole in a wall) with the /fill command but for some reason it won't let me.

/fill 240 159 -277 243 73 -347 minecraft:obsidian

Have I done something wrong on the command?

I'm on version 1.14

Answer (score 0):

If it says the position is not loaded, then it means it is outside of loaded chunks. To fix this, break your command into two or more /fill commands along the longest axis. In this case, you could use these:

```
/fill 240 159 -277 243 100 -300 minecraft:obsidian
/fill 240 100 -277 243 73 -300 minecraft:obsidian
/fill 240 159 -300 243 100 -347 minecraft:obsidian
/fill 240 100 -300 243 73 -347 minecraft:obsidian
```

By breaking the region into a few portions, you ensure that whatever portion you are trying to fill is loaded.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for -10000 to 10000 quickly?